# what is a vps IP in amazon web service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I have a Amazon web sever VPS and I ran a node js app on port 5000(I have checked this port and it was empty).
my node js app receive a simple get request and send a simple get request to another server.
But now I don't know what IP I should send request for node js(I don't know where is my app running)
I tested the IP that AWS gave to us but I see the error that IP is unreachable.
I also open firewall on port 5000(I ran `ufw allow 5000` in terminal), and even I write a code on vps to send a request to localhost:5000 but the node JS didn't receive the request(I'm sure that localhost doesn't work).
I ran my node js app and ran this code in terminal:

`sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`

and I see this :

`0.0.0.0:5000`

what should I do for Fixing my app?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is "firewall" in you message. If AWS provisioned a public IP address for your EC2 instance you still should setup you VPC to allow traffic on port 5000. So:

1. Check the security group that is assigned to your EC2 instance. Incoming traffic on TCP port 5000 should be allowed.
2. Check you network ACL. Both incoming ***and** outgoing traffic on port 5000 should be allowed.

You're also responsible for setting up an internet gateway in your VPC to route traffic and adding corresponding rules to the route table that's attached to your network.